# Combining data frames in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have some currencies in json files, I created. For example

```
[{"AUD":"2.8681"},{"AUD":"2.8667"},...], [{"BRL":"1.1607"}, {"BRL":"1.1645"},...].

import json
 import pandas as pd
 with open('AUD.json') as f:
    AUD = json.load(f)
 with open("BRL.json") as f:
    BRL=json.load(f)
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(AUD)
 df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(BRL)
 print(df+df2)
```

Output is

```
 AUD  BRL
0    NaN  NaN
1    NaN  NaN
2    NaN  NaN
       ...
```

What I want is

```
 AUD  BRL
0    2.8681  1.1607
1    2.8667  1.1645
2    2.8679  1.1634
     ...
```

Thank you in advance for your solutions ;)

Edit:
`print df.head()
 AUD
0  2.8681
1  2.8667
2  2.8738
3  2.8589
4  2.8598`

df2.head() works also well

`print(pd.concat([df,df2])`

Output

`AUD     BRL
0    2.8681     NaN
1    2.8667     NaN
...
124     NaN  1.0299
125     NaN   1.033`

Comment: Please include the output of `df.head()` and `df2.head()` in the question. Apparently, you want to _concatenate_ the DataFrames, not _add_ them, don't you? Then you should use `pd.concat`, not `+`.

Comment: `pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

`pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)`

Output will be of form:

```
       AUD  BRL
0   2.8681  2.8681
1   2.8667  2.8667
2   2.8738  2.8738
3   2.8589  2.8589
4   2.8598  2.8598
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a little mistake, what you want to do is

```
pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```